# В чём разница между StackOverFlowError и OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, jvm, outofmemoryerror, stackoverflow

`StackOverFlowError` и `OutOfMemoryError` выбрасываются при недостатке памяти у `jvm`, но в чём их разница?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435613/whats-the-difference-between-stackoverflowerror-and-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **StackOverFlowError**

Эта ошибка происходит, когда переполнен *стек* (по-английски - *stack*). Если кратко, то
в стеке хранятся только **ссылки** на объекты, которые находятся в *куче*. Ещё в стеке хранятся примитивы и список методов, "кто кого вызвал". Вообщем `StackOverFlowError` происходит при зацикливании вызова методов. Например:

```java
public static void doSomething(){
    doSomething();
}
```

При вызове метода `doSomething()` произойдёт `StackOverFlowError`, так как стек будет переполнен.

Чтобы исправить `StackOverFlowError` нужно найти такое зацикливание и убрать его. На самом деле, вызов метода из самого себя использовать можно, но делать это стоит осторожно. Это будет называться *рекурсия*. Вот пример использования рекурсии для вычисления факториала:

```java
public static int factorial(int number){
    if(number < 0){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Число меньше 0");
    }  
    if(number == 0 || number == 1){
       return 1;
    }
    return factorial(number - 1) * number;
}
```

В таком случае `StackOverFlowError` **не** произойдёт, так как из метода в конце-концов будет выполнен выход.

В рекурсивных методах следует также проверять, что число, пришедшее в параметрах, не слишком большое. В противном случае может оказаться, что метод будет вызывать сам себя хоть и не бесконечное, но всё же достаточное количество раз, чтобы произошла ошибка `StackOverFlowError`.

### **OutOfMemoryError**

Это ошибка происходит, когда переполнена *куча* (по-английски - *heap*). Если кратко, то в *куче* хранятся объекты. Именно **объекты**, а не ссылки на них. То есть `OutOfMemoryError` произойдёт тогда, когда в куче кончится место создавать объекты. Вот пример:

```java
public class Test{

  public static void main(String [] args){ 
      Object[][] toManyObjects = new Object[1000000][1000000];
  }

}
```

Этот код  бует скомпилирован, но при запуске произойдёт `OutOfMemoryError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

Ведь в массиве гигантское количество объектов, и в куче нет столько места.

Конечно, никто не будет делать такие глупые ошибки. Обычно `OutOfMemoryError` происходит тоже при зацикливании, но не при бесконечном вызове метода, а в обычных циклах (`for`, `while`, `do-while`), если из таких циклов нет выхода, а в теле цикла создаются какие-либо объекты.

Примеров кодов с `OutOfMemoryError` масса в интернете: можете посмотреть вопросы на `StackOverFlow на русском`, в которых упоминается `OutOfMemoryError`, если вам интересно посмотреть в каких случаях такая ошибка может произойти.

### **Подведу итоги**

- `OutOfMemoryError` происходит при переполнении кучи, а `StackOverFlowError` - при переполнении стека;
- `StackOverFlowError` происходит при бесконечном вызове метода, а
  `OutOfMemoryError` - при зацикливании создания объектов;
- И того, и другое нужно исправить: найти зацикливание и устранить его.

### **Ссылки**

[Статья на хабре про память в java](https://habr.com/ru/post/549176/)

[Ещё одна статья на хабре про память в java](https://habr.com/ru/post/510454/)

[Пост на английском StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435613/whats-the-difference-between-stackoverflowerror-and-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Если рекурсивная функция сделана правильно (без бесконечного выполнения), то это ещё не значит, что ошибка `StackOverflowError` гарантированно не произойдёт. Ведь исходные данные для рекурсии могут быть слишком большими (например, для факториала задать 1_000_000), в таком случае метод будет вызываться хоть и не бесконечное, но всё же достаточное число раз для того, чтобы произошла `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @Byb если рекурсивная функция сделана верно, то в ней будет проверка на то, что число слишком большое =)

Comment: @Byb поправил ответ

Comment: методо  `factorial`: (1) неверный возвращаемый тип (ошибка компиляции); (2) не учитывая отрицательные числа, при валидном `0` получем всё-таки `SO`.

Comment: @siarhei987 снова поправил ответ.